# How do I build a pre-release package with the .net Core build task

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, nuget-package

I have a solution that contains a number of `csproj`'s.

In my CI, I want all csproj to build both a pre-release package, with the build number as prerelease string, and a release package with the regular version number.

Later, in a release step, I want to push all pre-release packages automatically, and be able to make a manual release for each release package individually.

My `csproj` file contains

```
<VersionPrefix>1.8.0</VersionPrefix>
<VersionSuffix>$(VersionSuffix)</VersionSuffix>
```

From the CLI, I would build a pre-release version with `dotnet pack --version-suffix foo` to build version `1.8.0-foo`, and use `dotnet pack` without additional arguments to build version `1.8.0`

I'm trying to use the `.net Core 2.*` build task. I'm seeing automated versioning under pack options/automatic versioning, but those seem to ignore the version prefix in the `csproj` file.

How do I configure things so that the same `csproj` can be built in to a pre-release package in one task, and into a release nuget package in another, that differ only in that one has a version suffix set to the build number, and the other without a version suffix?

EDIT:

I tried setting `VersionSuffix=bar` in additional properties, but this gave me a rather uninformative error:

log:

> 2018-05-07T10:31:27.1536721Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
>
> 2018-05-07T10:31:27.1629285Z Active code page: 65001
>
> 2018-05-07T10:31:28.1487070Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" 
>   pack D:\a\1\s\path\to\some.csproj --output D:\a\1\a /p:Configuration=release;$VersionSuffix=bar --verbosity Detailed
>
> 2018-05-07T10:31:28.3350467Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.6.84.34536 for .NET Core
>
> 2018-05-07T10:31:28.3351167Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> 2018-05-07T10:31:28.3351324Z
>
> 2018-05-07T10:31:28.4870038Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
>
> 2018-05-07T10:31:28.4881392Z ##[error]An error ocurred while trying to pack the files.

Comment: Do you solve his issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add additional task for pre-release package:

1. .NET Core task (Automatic package versioning: `Off`)
2. .NET Core task (Automatic package versioning: `Off`; Additional build properties: `VersionSuffix=foo`)

Comment: @Martijn The value of Additional build properties is `VersionSuffix=foo` instead of `$VersionSuffix=foo` (Remove `$`)

Comment: Ah, that fixes it.

Comment: OK, but how do I substitute that foo from the build environment. I tried `VersionSuffix=CI-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)-$(Rev:r)`, but it is simply inserted verbatim.